# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate updating the wrong entity

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use mongoose 5.4.13 and found a strange behaviour:
if I use

```
mymodel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id: '5c6ad3b1385ae7000e6c3c2c'}, //
    updateObject)
```

it updates the wrong object. Instead of `objectId` `5c6ad3b1385ae7000e6c3c2c` it updates `5beac8adeff330000ecfd957` for some reason.

If I convert the `id` to an `objectid` it works as expected. But `findById`, for example, works without converting. So what is the reason for this?

As mentioned in the documentation, mongoose should cast the values for me.

**Edit:**

```
const schema: Schema = new Schema(
    {
        deviceToken: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        locale: {
            type: String,
            default: 'en',
            required: false,
        },
        userUid: {
            type: Schema.Types.String,
        },
        orders: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Order'
        }],
        table: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Table',
            required: true,
        },
        venue: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Venue',
            required: true,
        },
    }, { timestamps: true }
);
export default model<MgSession>('Session', schema);
export const sessionSchema: Model<MgSession> = model<MgSession>('Session', schema);
```

Comment: can you share your _model_ file?

Comment: @molamk added. Just basic stuff.

Comment: that's strange indeed. Everything here checks out, I think the problem may be somewhere else. Are you __positive__ that this request updates another document?

Comment: I thought the same and yes, I am sure it updates the wrong document.